# how to use @OrderBy with Embeddable in spring boot jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have 3 entity Unit, Off, Position. in my Unit have an constrain one to many with list offs, off have position. I want to Order by code in `position.code`, how can I make it

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "unit")
public class Unit{

 @Id
 @Column(name = "id")
 private Long id;

 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinClolumn(name = "unit")
@ElementCollection
 @OrderBy("position.code")
 private List<Off> offs;
}
```

this is my Entity Off

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "off")
@Embeddable
public class Off{

 @Id
 @Column(name = "id")
 private Long id;

 @Column(name = "cate_position")
 private Long catePosition;

 @ManyToOne
 @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
 @JoinClolumn(name = "cate_position")
 @Embedded
 private Position position;
}
```

this is my Entity Position

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "position")
@Embeddable
public class Position{

 @Id
 @Column(name = "id")
 private Long id;

 @Column(name = "code")
 private String code;
}
```

How can I sort List offs in Unit entity by 'position.code', it always throws invalid column name 'position'. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Annotate the entity class Off with @Embeddable
and now include the following code above the List

```
@ElementCollection
@OrderBy("position.code DESC")
private List<Off> offs;
```